# Creating a loop through dataframes to create a 10 ggplots

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, ggplot2

I am looking to create a loop (if possible!) whereby this code:

```
ggplot(Sphere_Run1_Call_2019, aes(x=Time..Seconds.)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Accx), color = "darkred") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Accy), color="steelblue", linetype="solid") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Accz), color="green", linetype="solid") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  ggtitle("Run 1") + 
  xlab("Time (Seconds)") + 
  ylab("Acceleration (m/s2)")
```

is repeated through 9 more dataframes (Sphere_Run2_Call_2019, Sphere_Run3_Call_2019, etc...) to generate 10 graphs i can export.

is this possible in ggplot? and is Looping best in this instance?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If your all your dataframes have similar structure you could append them in a list and map ggplot function over them, example:



mtcars1 <- sample_frac(mtcars,0.5)
table_list <- list(dataframe1 = mtcars1,dataframe2 = mtcars)

map(table_list,~ggplot(.,aes(mpg,disp))+
      geom_line())

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
for(i in seq(10)){
  ggplot(get(paste("Sphere_Run",i,"_Call_2019",sep="")), 
    aes(x=Time..Seconds.)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = Accx), color = "darkred") +
    geom_line(aes(y = Accy), color="steelblue", linetype="solid") +
    geom_line(aes(y = Accz), color="green", linetype="solid") +
    theme_classic() +
    ggtitle("Run 1") +
    xlab("Time (Seconds)") +
    ylab("Acceleration (m/s2)")
}
```

Comment: how do i get seq (10) to understand that its Sphere_RunX_Call_2019 df's i want it to read?

Comment: Seq(10) just creates a vector from 1 to 10. Is the get() inside the loop that retrieves the right data frame for you.